# Canvas App - Connect to Another Orgs VFP using Web server flow + API User

Tags: api, webservices, oauth2, canvas

I am trying to wrap my head around Salesforce Canvas apps and its authentication.

My test use case is to be able to access / interact with a visual-force page located in another Salesforce org.

**Example:**

- Org 1 - User visits contact record -> canvas app loads -> shows
  visual force page from org 2 with some details they have about that
  contact.
- Org 2 - Hosts the visual force page that receives a `contactId` and
  shows the relevant information.

The part I am stuck on is authentication.

The user in Org 1 does not have an account in Org 2 to authorize with.

Instead, I was hoping I could use web server flow to connect org 1 and org 2 together using a refresh token and an API user account.

I do something similar with named credentials. When you set up the named credentials (after defining the auth provider), it starts the login flow so that you can connect the two orgs together by logging in as that API user.

The token is then created and going forward, any calls made through the named credentials uses that token.

On the following documentation, it shows that OAuth with Canvas supports web sever flow (if I am reading this right).

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_oauth_authentication.htm

I setup my canvas app and I have it pointing to Org 2’s visual force page.

How would I go about initiating this login flow so that I can login with my API user and allow that token to be then used to connect going forward?

I don’t see anything like the named credentials "Start Authentication Flow on Save” option.

Since the canvas app URL is pointing directly to another orgs VFP, it's throwing a cors eror "refused to display `...` in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. This is because it is unable to establish the connection to the other org, so takes you to the login page, and SF doesn't allow the login page to be framed.

Is it possible to do what I am trying?

Comment: This article about displaying a VF page from an org which is acting as a Service Provider is a little bit dated but the flow is the same as it would be implemented today leveraging SAML SSO for authentication. [Implementing SAML SSO for Canvas Apps](https://developer.salesforce.com/index.php?title=Implementing_SAML_SSO_for_Canvas_Apps&oldid=94531)

Comment: Thanks, @MarkPond - I actually came across this in my research, but I don't think the SAML applies to me here. There isn't a user account in the org with the VFP that the SAML would be authing with. Essentially when a user in org 1 visits a page, they have no idea that it pulled in data from another org. They arent authenticating anything them self and would never see a prompt asking them to login. The web server flow should allow me to login as the API user so that it generates the refresh token that is then used going forward.

Comment: Salesforce does allow you to do [just-in-time User provisioning in an org with an SSO flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_jit_about.htm&type=5), in the event that you want to pursue the SSO solution further.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkPond - I'm not wanting to create users in the other org to consume licenses etc. My hope was that I could just use a single API user that connected the two orgs together, allowing that session to provide access to the canvas app as the API user. This would mean that when bob,sally, or fred visit the page with the canvas app, its pulling in a visual force page from the other org as the authenticated API user.